# Coding an iterator to traverse binary tree

Tags: javascript, python, closures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The question is, given a BST, find out whether there are two numbers that add up to a given number `k`. No extra memory should be used.

Now if it were a sorted array, I could have simply kept two pointers, one at the beginning, one at the end. At each step I would compute the sum of the two numbers pointed by the pointers, if the sum were less than k, I would have incremented the starting pointer, else decremented the end pointer until there is a match, or the pointers overlap.

I can do the same thing with the BST, converting it into a sorted array through inorder traversal, but that requires extra memory. So I think an iterator solution would be in order. I would keep two iterators, one would traverse the BST in the normal inorder manner, calling which will return the next bigger number, and the other would traverse the BST in reverse-inorder way, returning the next smaller number upon each call.

Any idea how to design such iterators? I would prefer a solution in Python/Javascript. Although Python provides functions like `iter`, I want to design it using closures.

Comment: You can traverse a BST in order without copying it into an array -- it's just a depth-first search. Are you asking how to write that?

Comment: I don't know if they'll help, but Nicholas Zakas has a two-part series on BST's in Javascript: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/tag/binary-search-tree/

Comment: @katrielalex, Not exactly. I am looking for an iterator, which will remember the last node visited, so that on subsequent call, it returns the next node..

Comment: @Cupidvogel, yield was designed exactly for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of iterators (using closures) are called generators in python.

Generators are functions, using 'yield' keyword instead of 'return'. When yield is encountered, the respective value is returned, but the execution state of the function is suspended, until the next value is required.

So, you can just implement a tree-traversal function, using 'yield' instead of 'return', and your goal will be accomplished.

They are very easy to design:

```
# Simple tree definition
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

# In-order lazy iterator (aka generator)
def inorder(tree):
    if tree is not None:
        for x in inorder(tree.left):
            yield x
        yield tree.data
        for x in inorder(tree.right):
            yield x

# Reverse in-order lazy iterator
def rev_inorder(tree):
    if tree is not None:
        for x in rev_inorder(tree.right):
            yield x
        yield tree.data
        for x in rev_inorder(tree.left):
            yield x

# Construct a tree
n1 = Tree(1)              
n2 = Tree(2)              
n3 = Tree(3)              #         7
n4 = Tree(4)              #       /   \
n5 = Tree(5, n1, n2)      #     5       6
n6 = Tree(6, n3, n4)      #    / \     / \
n7 = Tree(7, n5, n6)      #   1   2   3   4

for i in inorder(n7):
    print i, 
print

for i in rev_inorder(n7):
    print i, 
print
```

Output:

```
1 5 2 7 3 6 4
4 6 3 7 2 5 1
```

To manually iterate, use:

```
gen = rev_inorder(n7)
print gen.next()       # Output 4
print gen.next()       # Output 6
```

Comment: Well, that's kind of neat, but I was looking for a solution without using `itertools` or `yield` kind of stuff. Is that do-able?

Comment: @Cupidvogel, you asked for a solution using closures, but that's what yield represent. This is the right way to do these kind of things in python.

Comment: `looking for a solution without using itertools or yield kind of stuff` is silly. That is how you write iterators in Python.

Comment: Note BTW that the recursive solution, while being much more elegant, is not necessarily the best, because Python isn't good at recursion. Specifically, this is no longer constant space, because each recursive call generates a stack frame. You can write a constant-space version by traversing iteratively: go to the left child unless it doesn't exist, then the right child, then up; if you've come from the right child then go up again.

Comment: Note also that `to manually iterate` is correct in this case, but in general one iterates over iterators with `for` loops.

Comment: @katrielalex, you are right, but I never experienced performance problems of kind recursive/iterative traversal of trees. I just presented an example for how to use yield, OP could easily redesign for traversing iteratively. Also, regarding to manually iterating, this is what OP wants (when saying about incrementing/decrementing the startup pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I come up a simple idea ;-): 
If you don't want to allocate extra space for iteration around the BST, then the performance needs to be sacrificed.

```
var inst = new BST();
inst.Insert(-121);
inst.Insert(13);
inst.Insert(1);
inst.Insert(10);
GetAddends(inst, 55); // here we go
function GetAddends(bst, target) {
    var iter1 = bst.GetIterator();
    var iter2 = bst.GetIterator(false);

    while (iter1.IsValid() && iter2.IsValid() && (iter1.Pos() < iter2.Pos())) {
        var temp = iter1.data() + iter2.data();
        if (temp < target) iter1.Next();
        else if (temp > target) iter2.Next();
        else window.alert(iter1.data() + "+" + iter2.data() + "=" + target);
    }
    bst.ClearIterators();
}

function BST() {
    var _root, _nodeCount, _locked;
    this.Insert = function(data) { 
        if (_locked === true) throw "could not modify the BST during iteration";
        _nodeCount++;
    }
    this.Delete = function(data) {
        if (_locked === true) throw "could not modify the BST during iteration";
        _nodeCount--;
        return null;
    }
    this.GetIterator = function(isForward) { return Iter(isForward); }
    this.ClearIterators = function() { _locked = false; }

    function Iter(isForward) {
        if (isForward == null) isForward = true; // if the parameter is omitted, then true by default
        _locked = true;
        var _pos = isForward ? 0 : (_nodeCount - 1);
        var _curData;
        return function() {
            this.IsValid() {
                return (isForward ? (_pos < _nodeCount) : (_pos >= 0));
            }
            this.Next = function() {
                isForward ? _pos++ : _pos--;
                _curData = null;
            }
            this.Pos = function() { return _pos; }
            this.Data = function() {
                if (_curData == null) { /* loop the BST and find _posTH node and stored in the _curData in case we need it later */ }
                return _curData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The codes not implement the BST, but the idea should be clear. Have fun! Reminder here, we don't allow to modify the BST when in the mid of holding an iterator. After we do not within the scope of holding iterator, we need to call ClearIterators(). However, an elegant solution for this could be to use PUB/SUB to let BST know how many iterators are existing. Maybe this could be another question, ha.